# Application Insights Analytics - Chart X axis

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics, aiql

How can I render a chart for the query

```
performanceCounters
| where name == "% Processor Time" 
| summarize avg(value) by bin(timestamp, 5s),cloud_RoleInstance
```

where i get a point for every 5 seconds and not every 1 min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perf counters are collected at a regular interval (about 1 min) the effect of the bin function will move the time stamp to the nearest 5 second interval. What you're seeing is because of the counter collection interval and you won't get that granularity. You would need to implement your own module to do that.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/v2.3.0/Src/PerformanceCollector/Shared/PerformanceCollectorModule.cs#L49